# find -newer to detect only newly copied files

Tags: linux, shell, find

I am using the following code

```
if [ ! -f $time_mark ]
then
    touch $time_mark
fi

cp -f aaa.txt bbb.txt ccc.txt $file_dir
find $file_dir -newer $time_mark > file_list.txt
...
```

I am using **find -newer** to send only files are that copied later than **$time_mark**.  But it turns out that if **$time_mark** does not exist for first time, it will execute **touch $time_mark** and start copying files, which can happen almost at the same time.  This results in **$time_mark** and copied files having the same system time, and the whole concept of sending only files copied later than **$time_mark** doesn't work.

Is there some way to work around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ -f $time_mark ]
then
    incremental="-newer $time_mark"
else
    incremental=""
    touch $time_mark
fi

...
find $file_dir $incremental > file_list.txt
...
```

Even better would seem to execute the touch conditionally (only if the prior run succeeded?)

I strongly suggest to look at `rsync`, `rdiff-backup`, or other (backup?) tools that grok incremental change detection.

As a very simple measure, since you seem to hint you want to copy these files (?) somewhere, simply copying with `-pu` (`--preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps --update`) could do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use "cp -p" to preserve timestamps of the original files.